How to sync files with rclone excluding extensions that have more than 3 characters
I'm syncing some files in my S3 bucket with rclone and all is ok.
I need to exclude from sync all files with more than 3 characters on extensions (e.g. test.jfjaoisfn) in case of ransomware attack or events like that.
Is there a way to use a variable?
Thanks a lot and have a great day.
Giulia
I read a lot of informations but i don't know what's the better solution.
